# "Consumato/a in casa" oppure "consumato/a a casa"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Qual è la preposizione corretta nell'espressione "consumato/a   _ _ _    casa", "in" oppure "a"?

Ad esempio, qual è la forma corretta fra le seguenti?

> - Una buona parte dell'energia consumata *in* casa viene usata per il riscaldamento.
> - Una buona parte dell'energia consumata *a* casa viene usata per il riscaldamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo caso io direi

> Una buona parte dell'energia consumata **in** casa viene usata per il riscaldamento

per riferirmi alla casa come luogo fisico. Con "in casa" l'affermazione suona neutrale e generale, come se stessimo parlando del risultato di qualche studio o statistica.

Se invece diciamo

> Una buona parte dell'energia consumata **a** casa viene usata per il riscaldamento

il lettore o ascoltatore ha l'impressione che l'autore della frase stia parlando della propria casa (o quantomeno, più che se avesse detto "in casa").

In certi contesti, come nell'esempio, "in casa" è più neutrale rispetto a "a casa", che spesso comunica invece un aspetto o implicazione personale. In altri casi c'è poca differenza.

---

Da notare che se aggiungiamo un possessivo, gli esempi diventano praticamente equivalenti:

> Una buona parte dell'energia consumata in casa **nostra** viene usata per il riscaldamento
>
> Una buona parte dell'energia consumata a casa **nostra** viene usata per il riscaldamento